Why isn't hledger import parsing epoch timestamps?
I have a CSV with rows like this:
1724760000,"American Express","Payment",1234.56

When I run hledger import data/tmp.csv -f data/current.ledger --rules-file data/checking.csv.rules with date-format set to %s (number of whole seconds since the Unix epoch), the journal entries have dates that are all 1970-01-01, but they should be 2024-08-27. Am I missing something here, or is this a bug?
The entire rules file:
fields date, payee, description, amount
date-format %s
currency $
account1 Checking


Contact the folks who support hledger. They're the ones who will know the limitations and/or bugs of their software.

Thought I'd try here first. Parsing epoch doesn't seem very common, so maybe the question can be helpful to someone later.

I'm curious, is this a real data set that you downloaded from an account you have? I don't understand why any bank would give an export of transactions with epoch time.

The CSV is based on data from MX. Banks do lots of strange things, but I also think it's silly to use epoch time here. Alas, it's what I've got to work with and it beats manually downloading CSVs from my bank. ‍♂️

hledger is trying to read a date, but the time library hledger is using will not parse a date from %s (only a time, rightly or wrongly: UTCTime or ZonedTime types).
Perhaps it can be made to work with some more dev work. Interesting real world example, I wouldn't have expected this from a bank either..

Thanks for confirming, Simon! It's a bit of an odd workflow: I query transactions from MX via SimpleFin and output those as CSV for hledger. I could just have my script output ledger entries, but I want to use hledger's rules, so that's what I came up with.

Seems to me that the simplest fix is to write a preprocessor which converts those dates into a form your software likes.

Ah. Pragmatically, probably the thing for now is make your script do the seconds to date conversion to help hledger out.

Parsing during the transform step makes sense. I get a good result. Thanks! ✨
